# Display webmenu on webbrowser control on ms access form isn't like a firefox browser or other bw

Tags: html, css, ms-access, webbrowser-control

I have webbrowser control om my ms acess form.
I use a html code to show in wb on my access form but it isn't like a webbrowser

my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color:#4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

when I open ms access form thing that i see is different of that is displayed in webbrowser.
I am sure there is a way to solve  for this problem, therefore please help me.
my sample is below:
[display html and css code on ms access](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1szPN72mcqNZb_-BIEvtNn970_Z3tzy0S)

Comment: Have in mind, that the web browser control uses the engine of _Internet Explorer_, so this is the browser to verify how your page could be expected to render.

Comment: You mean the html is different from your browser? If yes every software render the web component if different manner. Dropdown in IE is different from chrome and different from firefox. If you want they look the same you have to reset the browser CSS before. (i.e. https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6)